# How to concat the api inputs in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

MY  file API code

```
var enquiryDetails = {
  "source":"https://enroll.unicity.com",
  "customer" : {
    "id": {"unicity": $scope.id}, 
    "phone": $scope.phone, 
    "email": $scope.email, 
    "humanName": {"fullName": $scope.name}
  }, 
  "place": $scope.place,
  "subject": $scope.Subject,
  "contact":$scope.Contact,
  "message":$scope.message,
  "market": "IN"
};
```

I want as below.

```
Message: Subject: "Entered Subject"

Contact for: "Selected Contact For"

"Actual Message"
```

Comment: please create a plunker of the same

Comment: What do you mean by "I want as below"?

Comment: Include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var enquiryDetails = {
  "source":"https://enroll.unicity.com",
  "customer" : {"id": {"unicity": $scope.id}, 
  "phone": $scope.phone, 
  "email": $scope.email, 
  "humanName": {"fullName": $scope.name}}, 
  "place": $scope.place,
  "subject": "Subject: "+$scope.Subject,
  "contact": "Selected Contact For" + $scope.Contact,
  "message":$scope.message,
  "market": "IN"
};
```

It will work normally like..

```
"subject": "Subject: "+$scope.Subject,
"contact": "Selected Contact For :" + $scope.Contact,
```